# How to call a function which returns multiple values

Tags: python, function

How might one call a function which returns two variables?

For example:

```
def F1(x):
    do something with x
    return y, z

def F2(y, z, q):
    do lots of other things
    return profit
```

What syntax should be used to call `F1` from `F2` which makes in clear which output from `F1` is `y` and which is `z`.

My intuition says

```
F2(F1(x), q)
```

Which is fine, but then how to call `y` and `z` within `F2`?

Comment: why not just do `y,z = f1(x)  p =f2(y,z,q)`

Comment: Hi @Florin Ghita. Do you mean, for example, that I use the variable name returned in F1 to reference the value in F2?

Comment: @Busterdust, thanks! So outside F2 I would use y,z = F1(x) and then call these variables in F2? Is there a way to do this without the intermediate step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solution.
Your F1 return 2 values, but if you put directly on F2 parameters, F2 will see in input

```
(y,z) <--- tuple
q <--- variable
```

A solution is to store the return of F1 into 2 variables then passing them to F2

```
y,z = F1(x)
F2(y,z,q)
```

Another solution is the use of `*args`
First pass q, then y and z

```
def F2(q, *args):
    y, z = *args
    some other code

def F1(x):
    some code
    return y, z

F2(q, *F1(x))
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a very clear and informative answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `F2` function definition to following:

```
def F2((y, z), q):
```

and call it as:

```
F2(F1(x), q)
```

The 0th element of the returned tuple from `F1` will be taken as `y` from `F2` and 1st element of the returned tuple will be taken as `z`  from `F2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return into a tuple:

```
a, b = F1(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` to [*pass multiple positional arguments*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to your function :

Demo:

```
>>> def F(q,*args):
...    x,y=args
...    print x,y
...    print q
... 
>>> F('q',4,5)
4 5
q
```

And when a function returns multiple arguments, you can use `*` to unpack the tuple at call time, to pass all the arguments to function:

```
>>> def A():
...    return 5,6
... 
>>> F('q',*A())
5 6
q
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `F2` like that, you would use:

```
F2(*F1(x), q=q)
```

This unpacks the results of `F1`, and only named arguments can follow that kind of operation, so you have to call `q` by it's name. But it probably makes more sense to unpack the results of `F1` first.

```
y, z = F1(x)
F2(y, z, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but you can call `F2` as:

```
F2(F1(x)[0], F1(x)[1], q)
```

This will return `profit`